# How to run java code on the companion/controller computer in dronekit?

Tags: java, dronekit, dronekit-android

I'm using dronekit with SITL/3DR solo for a minimalistic prototype.

At one point I would like to move some of the ground control station code (written in Java/Scala) to the companion computer for better real-time handling. Only to find that Java is not included in its shipped Yocto linux (I can't find it in repository either).

Is there an easy way to install java on the companion computer?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, installing and running the Java version of the Dronekit API is not supported at the moment, so there's no available instructions on how to proceed.
Though installing Java should be as simple as running the Oracle Java installer for arm: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-arm-downloads-2187468.html

Comment: That's good enough, let me try, I was under the impression that the communication protocol between pixhawk and companion computer on Solo is similar to that between pixhawk and GCS on Iris+, Am I wrong on this?

Comment: Will get back to you later to tell you the result.